# Not able to setState in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

I am not able to call setState on parent from child component

I tried to resolve the issue by binding a function in parent component and calling setState in that function. I passed the function in props of the child component but it still not able to find the parent component setState function.

```
const CrewsAdapter = props => {
  if(props.data.loading) {
    return <View><Text>Loading crews</Text></View>
  }
  if(props.data.getAllCrews) {
      crewsNames= props.data.getAllCrews.map(crew => ({"value": crew.crewName}));
    return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}>
            <View style={[styles.container, { flex: 0.25 }]}>
              <Text style={styles.headerText}>Crews</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <View style={{ flex: 0.9 }}>
                <Dropdown label="Crews List"
                          data={crewsNames}
                          onChangeText = {(value) => {this.props.stateHandler(value)}}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Crew/>
            </View>
          </View>
    );
  }
  return <View><Text>No data</Text></View>
};

export default class CrewsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.stateHandler = this.stateHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      crewName: '',
    }
  }

  stateHandler(value){
    this.setState({crewName: value});
  }

  render() {
    const AllCrews = graphql(crewsList, {options: (props => ({}))})(CrewsAdapter);
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
          <ToolBar />
          <AllCrews stateHandler = {this.stateHandler}/>
          <CrewsListFooter navProps={{...this.props}}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to setState when dropdown changes.

```
<Dropdown label="Crews List"
                          data={crewsNames}
                          onChangeText = {(value) => {this.props.stateHandler(value)}}
                />
```

but I get the error: "undefined is not an object(evaluating _this.props.stateHandler"

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `onChangeText = {(value) => {props.stateHandler(value)}}`

Your child component is a stateless functional component - aka just a function - that takes `props` as an argument - in this case you don't access props via 'this.props' as it is not an instance of a `React.Component` - you just access it via `props.[propName]` like you are the rest of the props - so `this.props` is undefined.

Comment: Right answer! And just call parents function to setState if there is redux